# 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command even after I set Maven home and configure Jenkins Maven Installer?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I set the environment variables:

[image]

Added it to my Path:

[image]

Set up Maven path in Jenkins:

[image]

And still the following error is thrown when I try to build:

```
    [JenkinsExercise] $ cmd.exe /C "mvn install && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Proof that Maven is installed succesfully:
[image]

What is the issue?

Comment: If it doesn’t work after a reboot you did something wrong

Comment: I restarted my computer, but the issue still persist. What seems wrong? I did everything according to multiple sources on the internet

Comment: Interesting.  Does Jenkins run as you? Considered just telling it to get maven itself??

Comment: It was a mistake by my side. In the Project Settings -> modules I had to add the Maven Path too.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add Maven_path to my `Project Settings > Modules > Maven path.`